# Change font of react-select component using theme

Tags: material-ui, react-select

I'm trying to change the font of my entire react-select component (control, drop-down, etc). I'm using material-ui themes, so I tried setting theme:

```
<Select
  theme={theme}
/>
```

But that didn't work. This also didn't work:

```
  <Select
    theme={theme => ({
      ...theme,
      typography: {
        ...theme.typography,
        fontFamily: ["Montserrat", "sans-serif"].join(",")
      }
    })}
  />
```

[Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/qlnjjo2p19)

I figured out how to do it with styles ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/llvw6q5p0m)):

```
const customStyles = {
  container: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    fontFamily: ["Montserrat", "sans-serif"].join(",")
  }),
};

<Select
  styles={customStyles}
/>
```

But it would be nice to use themes, since I already created a theme with my font.

Comment: In your example theme is already available.. i have tried to show in example
check: https://codesandbox.io/s/9jx2z18jwy

if MuiProvider at root you get theme via this:
https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#withtheme---component---component

i have console logged both properties, to show how to use.

Comment: Thanks. Your example has:

    styles={{
              container: (provided, state) => ({
                ...provided,
                fontFamily: theme.typography.fontFamily
              })
            }}

Is there a way to use the theme attribute, instead of style attribute?

    theme = {theme}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the `theme.js` [file](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/theme.js) below you will notice that there no `font` option for now so no way to use this props to achieve what you're looking for.

```
import type { Theme } from './types';

export const colors = {
  primary: '#2684FF',
  primary75: '#4C9AFF',
  primary50: '#B2D4FF',
  primary25: '#DEEBFF',

  danger: '#DE350B',
  dangerLight: '#FFBDAD',

  neutral0: 'hsl(0, 0%, 100%)',
  neutral5: 'hsl(0, 0%, 95%)',
  neutral10: 'hsl(0, 0%, 90%)',
  neutral20: 'hsl(0, 0%, 80%)',
  neutral30: 'hsl(0, 0%, 70%)',
  neutral40: 'hsl(0, 0%, 60%)',
  neutral50: 'hsl(0, 0%, 50%)',
  neutral60: 'hsl(0, 0%, 40%)',
  neutral70: 'hsl(0, 0%, 30%)',
  neutral80: 'hsl(0, 0%, 20%)',
  neutral90: 'hsl(0, 0%, 10%)',
};

const borderRadius = 4;
const baseUnit = 4;  /* Used to calculate consistent margin/padding on elements */
const controlHeight = 38;  /* The minimum height of the control */
const menuGutter = baseUnit * 2;  /* The amount of space between the control and menu */

export const spacing = {
  baseUnit,
  controlHeight,
  menuGutter,
};

export const defaultTheme: Theme = {
  borderRadius,
  colors,
  spacing,
};

export type ThemeConfig = Theme | ((theme: Theme) => Theme);
```